# seaborn heatmap color scheme based on row values

Tags: python, heatmap, seaborn, color-scheme

I have a dataframe, reproduced partly as such:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
tab = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[ 46,  39,  25,  29,  21,  12,  33,  32,  70, 109, 144, 158, 161,
    184, 163, 113, 117,  82,  76,  88,  77,  76,  64,  35],
   [ 39,  33,  29,  29,  26,  14,  25,  33,  60,  83, 126, 117, 111,
    148, 141, 104,  92,  75,  78,  74,  63,  67,  52,  39],
   [ 30,  27,  14,  11,  20,  17,  21,  31,  48,  62,  83,  78,  88,
     90,  80,  67,  53,  61,  47,  54,  50,  48,  35,  26],
   [ 30,  24,  19,  15,  17,  10,  12,  18,  34,  69,  88,  79, 109,
     95,  89,  82,  53,  46,  53,  57,  39,  41,  26,  29],
   [ 37,  31,  18,  12,  30,  13,  15,  19,  51,  61,  74,  81,  77,
    100,  96,  74,  60,  57,  42,  48,  43,  40,  29,  25],
   [ 14,   8,  14,  11,  13,   7,   9,  15,  42,  49,  50,  44,  53,
     42,  31,  31,  30,  27,  33,  25,  27,  17,  20,  17],
   [ 10,  15,   6,  10,  15,  11,   7,  18,  28,  43,  49,  37,  41,
     33,  37,  32,  26,  28,  19,  24,  19,  19,  13,  18],
   [  9,   9,   8,  12,   7,  11,   4,   8,  14,  15,  23,  30,  29,
     34,  25,  39,  22,  20,  15,  23,  12,  19,  14,  13],
   [  0,   3,   4,   1,   1,   0,   3,   4,   4,   5,   3,   5,   6,
      7,   3,   3,   6,   4,   2,   3,   3,   2,   2,   2],
   [  3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   1,   1,   4,   8,   2,   4,   7,
      2,   2,   9,   3,   5,   1,   5,   2,   0,   4,   1]]), index = 
        ['Stadsdeel Zuid', 'Stadsdeel West', 'Stadsdeel Nieuw-West',
   'Stadsdeel Centrum', 'Stadsdeel Oost', 'Stadsdeel Noord',
   'Wijk 00 Amstelveen', 'Stadsdeel Zuidoost', 'Wijk 00',
   'Wijk 00 Aalsmeer'])
```

and I created a heatmap as such

```
ax = sns.heatmap(tab, linewidths=.5 ,robust=True ,annot_kws = {'size':14})
ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
ax.figure.set_size_inches((12, 10))
```

I would like though that values to anchor the colormap are based on min-max values **per row** so that also rows with lower values are well visible. (in reality the table contains many more rows with low values that the heatmap barely shows color-wise)

How to achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: Please post some raw data of your original dataset so we can reproduce you problem. It's hard to copy and paste data from images.

Comment: you are right. See updated answer

Comment: Sounds like you want to normalize the rows?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would normalize the `tab` rows by the maximum value in each row with:

```
tab_n = tab.div(tab.max(axis=1), axis=0)
```

where `tab_n` is the normalized tab having values in the range [0,1]. Hope that helps. Plotting `tab_n` should return an heatmap like this:

[image]

Comment: as easy as that. great.

Comment: I have a AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'div'
Do you have an idea ?

Comment: @JohanC still getting the same error using true_divide

Comment: @ranbar If `tab`  is a 2D numpy array (instead of a dataframe), you can try `tab_n = tab / tab.max(axis=1, keepdims=True)`

Comment: This works great thank you.