# Change the heat map so each column has it's shading adjusted independently?

Tags: python, seaborn, legend, heatmap

[My Seaborn heat map as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3g7H.png)

Is there a way to make the legend shade lighter or darker based on each feature's max and min, instead of grabbing them from the whole dataframe? Or is there a better way to go about visualizing this?

Comment: [Color scale by rows in Seaborn Heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984762/color-scale-by-rows-in-seaborn-heatmap) might help.

Comment: See also [seaborn heatmap color scheme based on row values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111075/seaborn-heatmap-color-scheme-based-on-row-values)

Comment: @JohanC That's the ticket! Thanks